# Check if string contains number AND an underscore AFTER a specific pattern with PHP

Tags: php

I want to check if a string which starts with `rfmn_ba_x` has any `number` then an `underscore` **straight after it**

Possible strings are like the following:

```
rfmn_ba_xadfwe_as // should return FALSE

rfmn_ba_xadfwe_as35353 // should return FALSE

rfmn_ba_x2_egdas_345 // should return TRUE

rfmn_ba_x58_5436436345_adsf // should return TRUE
```

Comment: _"I try to ..."_ - then you should have some attempts to show us now, yes?

Comment: @CBroe i tried to solve this issue with preg_split, preg_match, strpos and similiar but was not able to solve it by my own due to leck of knowledge. Looking online for a solution (incl. stackoverflow) also didnt work for me... I changed the text from the question to "How to..."

Comment: https://regex101.com is a good site to learn some basics about regular expressions.

Comment: Can you share examples of input and expected output?

Comment: @nice_dev -  updated my question and added what result (True / False) i expect from different strings

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/delete/dpPVrOOPxZpWYW2f9rp50sHE

Comment: Regex would be as simple as `^rfmn_ba_x\d+_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this which will return true if the text straight after `rfmn_ba_x` has an underscore then a number

```
function checkString($string){

    //Remove rfmn_ba_x
    $string = str_replace('rfmn_ba_x', '', $string);
    
    $string = str_split($string);
    
    //if $string contains underscore and numbers return true
    if(str_contains($string[1], '_') && preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $string[0]) ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

echo checkString("rfmn_ba_x2_egdas_345");
```

Comment: ´rfmn_ba_xadfwe_as35353´ what about this one - if i understand your code correct this also returns true which should be false

Comment: Edited to fix - should be working now

Comment: I will try it a bit later - looks promising. what are the ~...~ mean?